After creating dataframe df2, getting values as Ellipsis under column price_usd: No such column exists in the original CSV data source
Working with Pandas library on Jupyter notebook.
After creating dataframe df2, getting values as Ellipsis under column price_usd. No such column exists in the CSV and so not sure why the same added to the dataframe. Is it okay to ignore or delete this column from the dataframe?



Certainly the new column was created before by an instruction in a cell above. If you restart your kernel, load the data with pd.read_csv and display the df, that column shouldn't be there.

And if there is "Ellipsis" everywhere, I guess that the way the new column was created was not correct (maybe missing .loc).

Yes after restarting the kernel, price_usd column no more there.

You will doubtlessly have executed a line like df2['price_usd'] = ..., either a placeholder you put there yourself or one that was provided as part of the tutorial you seem to be following. Anyway, looks like this can be closed as not reproducible.
